# cURL command line upload multipart file

Tags: post, curl, multipartform-data, postman

I am trying to upload a file using cURL to a server. This is the command I am running:

```
curl -v -F content=out.txt -F upload=@/Users/serbans/out.txt -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"  -X POST  http://10.11.12.13:8080/myapp/v1/jobs/90/stages/91/resources/?relativePath=&description=&content=
```

This is the output I get:

```html
Connected to 10.11.12.13 (10.11.12.13) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /myapp/v1/jobs/90/stages/91/resources/?relativePath= HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.11.12.13:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 438
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------3d7cdcd27fb3bc0c
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 13:55:00 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
{
  "httpStatus" : 400,
  "message" : "Required MultipartFile parameter 'content' is not present"
* Closing connection 0
}
```

However, when I use Google Chrome's Postman, it works fine. This is how I do it in Postman:

- POST on http://10.11.12.13:8080/myapp/v1/jobs/90/stages/91/resources/?relativePath=&description=&content
- no headers specified
- the Body is specified as form-data, one single parameter named "content", for value I just have to upload the file.

Do you know what I can do about this?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Serban

Comment: You didn't quote the URL so the piece after the first ampersand wasn't sent. But the -X isn't needed and the -H option is probably not necessary either. If you only want one part, why do you specify two -F options?

Comment: Quoting the URL worked. Thanks!